# R Shiny display values of a SelectInput from bottom to top

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to display the value of a SelectInput above the input and not under it as it is as default?

here is a reproductible example :

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    selectInput("state", "Choose a state:",
                list(`East Coast` = list("NY", "NJ", "CT"),
                     `West Coast` = list("WA", "OR", "CA"),
                     `Midwest` = list("MN", "WI", "IA"))
    ),
    textOutput("result")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$result <- renderText({
      paste("You chose", input$state)
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: I don't understand. Why don't you simply reverse the lists ?

Comment: You can also have the input default to selecting whatever you'd like, including the last element of a list, using the ```selected``` argument inside ```selectInput```

Comment: maybe the OP wants to have a concise app without needing to scroll to see all the choices. Therefore, showing the list of choices above the selectInput (instead of below it) makes sense for me. However, I have no clue on how to do it

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear, i meant displaying the list above the input, not under it, (i've edited the question)

Comment: Ah ok. Wait,I think I have a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a CSS solution:

```
CSS <- "
.selectize-dropdown {
  bottom: 100% !important; 
  top: auto !important;
}
"

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML(CSS))
    ),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    selectInput("state", "Choose a state:",
                list(`East Coast` = list("NY", "NJ", "CT"),
                     `West Coast` = list("WA", "OR", "CA"),
                     `Midwest` = list("MN", "WI", "IA"))
    ),
    textOutput("result")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$result <- renderText({
      paste("You chose", input$state)
    })
  }
)
```